# Sql Performance join Vs co-related Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sqlperformance

TABLE : employee (id,mid,join_date)

Question - Find all employees who joined before their managers

Query 1:

```
Select E1.id
From Employee E1 JOIN Employee E2 ON E1.mid=E2.id
Where E1.join_date < E2.join_date
```

Query 2:

```
Select E1.id
From Employee E1
Where E1.join_date < (Select E2.join_date From Employee E2 where E2.id=E1.mid)
```

Which of them is correct? If both correct, then how is the performance?

Comment: Get the execution plans and compare. I would guess they should have a very similar -- if not identical -- execution plans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both correct.

Performance questions need to be tested on your data on your system.  However, with a primary key on `employee(id)`, I would expect both to have very similar performance.

You can check the execution plans to see if there is any difference.